# Should I be concerned about outliers in NB GLMM with an offset term?

Tags: outliers, model-evaluation, glmm, negative-binomial-distribution, count-data

I'm working on a negative binomial model for count data. Unfortunately I can't provide a more detailed description because I wasn't explicitly allowed to. All I can say now is that the data is about people (social sciences).

Here is my model:

```
model = glmmTMB(Y ~ offset(log(offset.var)) + X1 + X2 + X2.squared + X3 + X2:X3 + scale(X4a) + scale(X4b) + scale(X4c) + scale(X4d) + (1|factor),
                dispformula = ~ offset.var,
                family = "nbinom2",
                data = data)

# I included a dispersion formula because of the "residuals against predictor" plots
# it also seems to help the uniformity (KS) test
```

I used an excellent `DHARMa` library for diagnostics. Here are the main results (the best I've come to):
[image: plot(model_res), where model_res = simulateResiduals(model, n = 1000, seed = 123)]

The `testOutliers(model_res, type = "bootstrap")` comes out significantly. When I inspected the outliers, I found that there are 12 of them, they occur only on the right side (scaled residual = 1) and their problem is that they have *non-zero values in dependent variable* while having *very low (almost zero) values in the offset variable*. (But the Y values are not excessively high – those observations were excluded prior to the analysis.) Since I consider these observations valid, I decided to keep them in my analysis but I don't know if that's correct because they seem to highly confuse the overdispersion tests:

```
> performance::check_overdispersion(model)
       dispersion ratio =    64208237559.269
  Pearson's Chi-Squared = 64079821084150.227
                p-value =            < 0.001
# if I remove all 12 observations whose scaled residual == 1, I get dispersion ratio = 1.183


> DHARMa::testDispersion(model_res)
    DHARMa nonparametric dispersion test via sd of residuals fitted vs. simulated
                  data: simulationOutput
           dispersion = 0.35968
              p-value = 0.254
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
# {DHARMa} test doesn't detect any problem even with the 12 observations included, unlike {performance} test


> DHARMa::testZeroInflation(model_res)
    DHARMa zero-inflation test via comparison to expected zeros with simulation under H0 = fitted model
                  data: simulationOutput
          ratioObsSim = 1.0023
              p-value = 0.99
alternative hypothesis: two.sided


> performance::check_collinearity(update(model, . ~ . - X2.squared - X2:X3))
       Term  VIF   VIF 95% CI Increased SE Tolerance Tolerance 95% CI
         X1 1.09 [1.04, 1.20]         1.04      0.92     [0.83, 0.96]
         X2 1.12 [1.06, 1.22]         1.06      0.89     [0.82, 0.94]
         X3 1.02 [1.00, 1.37]         1.01      0.98     [0.73, 1.00]
 scale(X4a) 1.25 [1.17, 1.36]         1.12      0.80     [0.73, 0.85]
 scale(X4b) 1.12 [1.06, 1.22]         1.06      0.89     [0.82, 0.94]
 scale(X4c) 1.09 [1.04, 1.20]         1.04      0.92     [0.83, 0.96]
 scale(X4d) 1.04 [1.01, 1.22]         1.02      0.96     [0.82, 0.99]


> performance::check_autocorrelation(model)
OK: Residuals appear to be independent and not autocorrelated (p = 0.770).


# observed values:
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  10  11  12  14  15  16  20
563 170 119  56  25  40   5   1   6  19   1   1   1   3   1   2

# predicted values:
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  12  13  14  15  17  18  20  21  23  41  46
220 441 176  75  46   9  11   6   6   8   2   2   3   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1

# conditional R^2 = 0.3949, marginal R^2 = 0.3380 (if it helps)
```

My question is: **Is there anything I should do with the outliers or model performance?** I would appreciate any answers or suggestions.

You can download the anonymised dataset and some basic R script from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YFF_a9XlKZrarP0iviEklF2Kico7IMRN/view?usp=sharing).

*EDIT: I've clarified the statement about outliers and narrowed the focus of the question.*

Comment: "while having zeros in the offset variable" - this sounds like a red flag to me. Offset variables multiply on to the expectation, so having a zero here implies the expectation is zero (which is not possible for a N.B). Also, then if `dispformula = offset`, when `offset == 0` that means you're saying there's no residual variance.

Comment: I apologize for my inaccuracy and have already clarified the statement about outliers. Their offset.var values _are not_ zero (of course) but _very close to zero_. In fact, originally there were zeros, but in order to calculate the logarithm of the offset.var, I added a small number (1e-09) to the values.

Comment: I still suspect it's a problem. For example, if your offset is 1e-9, then the expectation is 1e-9 * (linear predictor), which will almost surely be very close to zero. What will the predicted value of a N.B with expectation approx. zero be? Zero! Do you have a strong theoretical reason for using that as an offset?

Comment: I believe that (unfortunately) I have a theoretical reason for using this variable as an offset. The more days one has spent doing something (= offset.var), the more times one could experience something (= dependent variable). And since it is legitimate to spend zero days doing something (= offset.var), and in our research we are interested in all possibilities, I thought it was correct to keep these (almost zero) values in the dataset. If there is a better solution, I'd be more than happy to hear it! Thank you for your replies so far :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the diagnoses in the comments.

If you include `offset(log(offset.var))` in your model, then you are *assuming* that the mean observed counts are strictly proportional to `offset.var`. In principle, observations with `offset.var` equal to 0 are *either* impossible (if >0 counts are observed) *or* provide no information (because the predicted value and the observed value should both be zero, independent of the value of any other covariates).

In the comments you say

> originally there were zeros, but in order to calculate the logarithm of the offset.var, I added a small number (1e-09) to the value

When you have a component in the model that isn't supposed to be zero, it is tempting to set zero values to "a very small value" on the assumption that will have the minimal effect on the model estimates; *however*, setting zero values to 1e-9 (for example) makes them **extreme** values on the log scale, making them into (artificially constructed) outliers. (This issue also arises when people are trying to log-transform continuous responses that contain zeros; when log-transforming counts, $\log(1+x)$ is a common (and natural) way to avoid the problem — we don't need to pick an *arbitrary* small value.)

The [Gordian solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordian_Knot) (Alexandrian solution?) to the problem of what to do with outliers is usually to fit the model twice, once with and once without the outliers, and see what difference it makes. (To prevent snooping, you should pre-specify which version of the model will be your primary result.) You can then report that "results with and without outliers were similar", or not, depending on the results.

If these outliers do make a big difference, then you may need to think much more carefully about what you're going to do with them. For example, maybe values of 0 for the offset variable really mean "less than 1 day" (depending on your experimental design), in which case it might make sense to (crudely) add 0.5 to the values?  If your exposure variable is discrete (days), it might make sense to add 1 instead ...

PS adding `offset.var` to control dispersion is not ridiculous, but in this case I think it's probably trying to patch the original self-inflicted problem of setting the zero values ...

Comment: Thank you, dear Ben, a lot. I ended up using slightly modified variable as an offset (I actually combined the original variable with another variable, and included this other variable also as a covariate). The problem with outliers disappeared after that. I deeply appreciate your response.